# How to read file outside of www directory

Tags: php

How to read file with php when that file is outside my site ( www or htdocs ) directory but is on server ?

Comment: What do you mean read a file? Open it with fopen()? Or retrieve it with a url?

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the full path (such as `/var/www/whatever`) or use relative paths.  (`../` means the directory right above the current one.)

Answer (score 0):

PHP should be able to access (include, fopen, etc.) any file on the server as long as it's in a path accessible by the web server process' owning user.  Accessing these files via URL, however, shouldn't be possible.